# ssh step on a Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying out the new declarative way of Jenkins, to do the simple task of deploying my app through `ssh`, I have a shell script `deploy.sh` which do basic things `git pull` or `git clone` and deploy using `docker-compose`, on my laptop I can run it as this `cat deploy.ssh | ssh user@remote`.

I didn't find a way to do this from my `Jenkinsfile`. I've been trying for a few days.

```
stage('deploy') {
   steps {
      sh 'cat deploy.sh | ssh user@remote'
   }
}
```

Am I on the wrong track? Is there another way to deploy code?

Comment: Did you try copy deploy.sh on remote and run it there?

Comment: 1. You have to have deploy.sh accessible for Jenkins master/slave, whichever is executing it
2. Your configuration have to be done on Jenkins master/slave, so that git can work properly

Comment: @Tirex Running deploy.sh on remote works fine. @BigGinDaHouse `deploy.sh` is on the git repository, so it is accessible to `Jenkins`.

Comment: You have to copy your deploy.sh script on the server where you are trying to run your application. Use Scp to copy the sh file and use sshagent plugin to run the shell script there.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Jenkins plugin named **SSH Pipeline Steps**
https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-steps/

With this plugin installed, you can define your Jenkinsfile like this:

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage('Deploy') {
        steps {
            echo 'Deploying..'
            
             script{
                 node {
                    def remote = [:]
                    remote.name = "node-1"
                    remote.host = "10.10.10.10"
                    remote.user = 'username'
                    remote.password = 'password'
                    remote.allowAnyHosts = true
                      stage('Remote SSH') {
                        writeFile file: 'abc.sh', text: 'ls'
                        sshCommand remote: remote, command: 'for i in {1..5}; do echo -n \"Loop \$i \"; date ; sleep 1; done'
                        sshPut remote: remote, from: 'abc.sh', into: '.'
                      }
                }
            }
        }
    }}}
```

}
}